# After logging off, user is able to see the workbench page by pressing back button of the browser

Tags: users

I am using workbench module to show the entry made by some particular user with some role when user is logged in he redirect to my workbench page and  as the user log out it redirect to home page and after pressing back button it redirects to my workbench page

Comment: Yep, their browser has cached it. You need to serve a cache-busting header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088616/browser-back-button-showing-the-page-from-cache

Comment: @Clive Shouldn't Drupal do it automatically? I believe I never had such problem, but I don't recall ever setting it up myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this in custom module and it works

```
<?php 
/**
 *Implements hook_init().
 */
function MY_MODULE_init() {
  drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
}
```